# Gridview SqlDataSource ; Error with edit from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview populated with an sqldatasource. One of the columns of the gridview is a templatefield which contains a label as ItemTemplate, but in the EditItemTemplate I have a dropdownlist, instead of a textbox. I wanted to be able to edit a value from a certain column by selecting from a list of possible values.
So I created a second sqldatasource in order to extract the values from the database. I bounded the 2 sqldatasources. Visually it's ok. When I click on edit, the dropdownlist appears with the values that I want inside of it. When I select one of the values and click update, I get the error "
Input string was not in a correct format." I think I know why this is happening. Probably the values from the dropdownlist are type string and what I need is integer because that is the type for this column. I have tried setting the UpdateParameter as type Int32 but no luck. Is there any way to do this ?

This is the code I have used, but I have changed the column names with "Column_1", "Column_2", etc. In this example, "Column_6" is the templatefield with the dropdownlist in the edit.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataUploadGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="First_DB" DataKeyNames="Column_3" >
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column_1" HeaderText="Column 1"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column_2" HeaderText="Column 2"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column_3" HeaderText="Column 3"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column_4" HeaderText="Column 4"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column_5" HeaderText="Column 5"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 6">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Second_DB" DataTextField="Column_6_Description" DataValueField="Column_6_ID"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column_6_ID") %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Edit" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="Delete" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="First_DB" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" OnSelecting="First_DB_Selecting" OnSelected="First_DB_Selected" OnInserted="First_DB_Inserted" OnInserting="First_DB_Inserting" OnDeleting="First_DB_Deleting" OnUpdating="First_DB_Updating"
                SelectCommand ="SELECT * FROM [tblFirst_DB] 
                UpdateCommand ="UPDATE [tblFirst_DB] 
                SET [Column_1] = @Column_1, 
                [Column_2] = @Column_2, 
                [Column_3] = @Column_3, 
                [Column_4] = @Column_4, 
                [Column_5] = @Column_5, 
                [Column_6] = @Column_6 
                WHERE [Column_3] = @Column_3" 
                DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM [tblFirst_DB] WHERE [Column_3] = @Column_3"
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_1" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_2" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_3" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_4" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_5" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_6" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Column_3" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Second_DB" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Column_6_ID], [Column_6_Description] FROM [tblSecond_DB]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Hopefully you are still here. So just to recap the problem. I'm getting an "
Input string was not in a correct format. " error because I need the Column_6 parameter to be integer and the values are coming from a dropdownlist which is probably making each value a string.

What can I do so that the value for Column_6 stays int upon updating it ? 
The only thing that comes to mind right now is to pass the parameter from the code behind somehow. When I select the dropdownlist value, I should trigger an OnSelectedIndexChanged event. I'm thinking here is where I should cast the Selected_ID to an integer and somehow feed it into the first sqldatasource. But the value would go into a label so that will turn it into a string again. So no use...I'm really stuck on this. Any help is welcome.

Thank you !

Update: I've noticed that if I remove all the UpdateParameters, except the one from Column_6, I'm not getting the error anymore. However the value is not going in the gridview. It's an empty cell. I looked in the DB and it's null.
I think it's null because in the UpdateParameters I now have:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Column_6" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

It's not getting the value from anywhere. It should get it from the Second_DB sqldatasource. I tried changing it to:

```
<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Column_6" ControlID="Second_DB" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

But it's not really working out like I expected. I feel like I'm getting closer but no idea why it's behaving like this.

Comment: Can you provide related code-behind which assign `Column_6` datasource parameter from `DropDownList`? I also think `SelectedValue` from DDL is a string, you need `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` for integer conversion.

Comment: I don't have a parameter that gets assigned to Column_6 in code behind. Should this be in First_DB_Updating ? I was thinking to have a ControlParameter in the UpdateParameters and bind it to the second SqlDataSource, but it's not working :) I already said the ddl has string values that fail to convert to int. The problem is that I don't know where to do this cast. I'll try adding a regular parameter in UpdateParameters and will do e.Command.Parameters["Column_6"].Value = Int32.Parse(...but what do I put here ? I guess I need something like Second_DB.SelectedValue)

Comment: While trying to pass the parameter in the code behind, I got this error: "An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'Column_6' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection."                                                                                       `protected void First_DB_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["Column_6"].Value = Int32.Parse(Second_DB.SelectCommand.ElementAt(0).ToString());
        }`  ...So it's basically saying that Second_DB doesn't have a parameter named Column_6. I wanted the first elem from select.

Comment: You're missed `@` in `Parameters` indexer: `e.Command.Parameters["@Column_6"].Value = int.Parse(Second_DB.SelectCommand.ElementAt(0).ToString())‌`